# How to add new activity to my existing project app in Android Studio?

Tags: android

What needs to be done to add a new activity to my existing project app that works and compiles.
i want to add new activity that contain a "start button",when user click on start button he continue to the rest off app.

Comment: please read these: [page1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [page2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [page3](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

right-click on the app folder -> New -> Activity -> Empty Activity.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an structure like this, then just:

[image]

And if you want that new activity the first on App launch, change the manifest like this

```
<activity android:name=".LaunchingActivityRecentlyAdded"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So that way, just add a button and make an intent to call the rest of the activities of the app

Comment: and what is the code that i have to add in new activity java file ?

Comment: None, android autogenerate the code necesary to show the empty activity.

Comment: But if you want to show another from it call an intent in onClickListener

btListe = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Button_Liste);
    btListe.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {    public void onClick(View v)
        {
            intent = new Intent(main.this, TheActivityYouWantToShow.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

Answer (score -1):

Right-click your project -> New -> Activity -> Empty Activity.

A corresponding view gets automatically generated, wehere you can drag-and-drop the stuff you need into the view.